# Parallel apply is not faster than regular apply pyhon

Tags: python, multiprocessing, apply

I am working with AWS sagemaker instance with 64 giga ram and 16 cpu cores.
I am trying to make apply faster but it doesnt work.
Here is my attempts with the corresponding time:

1. Regular apply - CPU times: user 1min 59s, sys: 3.51 s, total: 2min 3s, Wall time: 2min 3s

```
def get_item_list_per_date(date, ads_list, date_list):

      loc = date_list.index(date)
      updated_ads_list = ads_list[:loc]
      return updated_ads_list

    df['item_list_update'] = df.progress_apply(lambda x: get_item_list_per_date(date=x['date'], item_list=x['item_list'], date_list=x['date_list']),axis=1)
```

2. Apply using Pool  - CPU times: user 48.8 s, sys: 5.39 s, total: 54.2 s, Wall time: 5min 29s

```
       import multiprocessing as mp

        def fx(df):
            def __fx(s):
                date = s['date']
                date_list = s['date_list']
                loc = date_list.index(date)
                return s['item_list'][:loc]

            return df.apply(__fx, axis=1)

        def parallel_apply(df):
            dfs = filter(lambda d: not d.empty, np.array_split(df, mp.cpu_count()))
            pool = mp.Pool(1)
            per_date = pd.concat(pool.map(fx, dfs))
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            return per_date
```

3. Apply with dask - CPU times: user 7min 13s, sys: 10.7 s, total: 7min 24s, Wall time: 7min 16s

```
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import multiprocessing

    ddf= dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions= mp.cpu_count())
    df['item_list_update'] = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(lambda x: get_item_list_per_date(date=x['date'], item_list=x['item_list'], date_list=x['date_list']),axis=1)).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have some indication that the first approach is not parallelized? I believe pandas is already doing multi-threaded execution which is the fastest for [embarassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) tasks (has lowest overhead).

Comment: From what I have read, using dask or multiprocess should be faseter than apply.

Comment: Could it be to do with the pickle and unpickle cost of the dataframe? If it was, you could put it in shared memory and then it would be much quicker (might solve the problem of more than one worker as well).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with Pandas and less with Dask, but in any case you're making a pool with one worker:

```
pool = mp.Pool(1)
```

Which generally doesn't make much sense.

Also, I would recommend not using all of your cores because it can make your system very unresponsive. I normally leave 2 cores:

```
num_cores = max(mp.cpu_count()-2, 1)
```

And substituting that in your code would modify:

```
        dfs = filter(lambda d: not d.empty, np.array_split(df, num_cores))
        pool = mp.Pool(num_cores)
```

Comment: That's odd... Could you add a sample dataframe to your question so that we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

I would be using the python module called threading which runs the process on the same cpu but different threads. This prevents a huge cpu process startup time.

```
def func(data1,data2):
    # send request to an API maybe
    # or download a file
    return True

# You have like 1000 or more threads which means you can really split the processes
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    processes = [executor.submit(func, *[(data1, data2)]) for data1, data2 in datas]
    data = []
    for i in concurrent.futures.as_completed(processes):
        data.append(i.result())
```

## The difference between multiprocessing and multithreading

Use multiprocessing for CPU heavy stuff and multithreading for downloading files and such.

I used this module when I had to download a website and then translate the content into english with an API. That really increased my speed perfomance.

I'm not certain what you're trying to do. So if I were you, then I'd give multithreading a try.

Comment: The problem is that the method being called is likely being executed in C, in which case the GIL will stop all other threads being executed (hence why multiprocessing is required)